# Office JS - Support on Android

Tags: office-js

I might be completely missing it somewhere but is Office-JS supported on Android? I've seen comments from 2016 saying Android support is coming but nothing recently confirming it is supported. Can anyone confirm the status (sorry, not sure where else to ask)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the Outlook APIs in Office.js is supported on Android at the present time. See this article for details: [Office Add-in Availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability)

Comment: is there a roadmap to get other APIs (e.g. Excel) support for Android?

Comment: Support for Android is in the roadmap - however we don't have any target date to provide.